# Fit Div under fixed div with 100% height with no overflow

Tags: html, css

I have an easy and stupid problem. I'm trying to fit a div under another div with `height:100%` without producing overflow, just fitting in body's height.

Example not working: https://jsfiddle.net/L38cea2s/1/

**HTML:**

```html
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
html, body {
  height:100%;
}

#top {
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  background-color:red;
}

#left {
  width:70%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:green;
  float:left;
  display:block;
}

#right {
  width:30%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:yellow;
  float:right;
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
}
```

I don't know why on jsfiddle my divs are not ocuppying 100% of width's body. But as you can see on the example, there's overflow because there's another div above both divs. I don't want an `overflow:hidden`.

Thanks!

Edit:

I'm searching for something like this: **(Any div is behind any div)**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This jQuery might help

```
var body = $('body').height();
var top = $('#top').height();
var workoutheight = body - top;
$('#left').css('height',workoutheight);
$('#right').css('height',workoutheight);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L38cea2s/7/

Comment: This appears to work, thank you so much! But there's no solution with CSS?

Answer (score 1):

I did a CSS only solution

Get the updated markup from JSFiddle

CSS

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.sidebar {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    background: #B2B200;
    height: 100vh;
}
.main-content {
    width: 80%;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
}
.top {
    height: 20%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #26FF5C;
    height: 20vh;
}
.left {
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
    background: #4DFFFF;
    height: 80vh;
}
.right {
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    background: #8500B2;
    height: 80vh;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aq8awrnz/

Comment: That's what I was looking for! But Sidebar should have a fixed width like I don't know 100px, but when I do that to your jsfiddle, the other divs have a margin on the right side, why? And top a fixed height: 50px

Comment: This is where the other divs are in a container with 80% if you put a fixed with on that container it will work

Comment: I don't know how to explain what Is what I'm exactly looking for, I updated the image above, so maybe then you understand my problem :P

Comment: If you add a fixed width to .main-content aswell it will be fixed https://jsfiddle.net/aq8awrnz/2/

Comment: Yeah, but main content should be height:100% so left and right can too. Sidebar should have width fixed and top height fixed, as I painted on the picture above. What I could do is this: https://jsfiddle.net/aq8awrnz/3/ but I don't know how to edit main content to fit on 100% of width's body

Comment: I think the only other way is jquery as i dont think you can achive what you want with just css

Comment: I think I can do this with CSS only, I got this https://jsfiddle.net/aq8awrnz/3/ I'm very close to what I was looking. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ive added calc Oops D'oh said about to my example  https://jsfiddle.net/aq8awrnz/4/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `calc` in your CSS as well... Example:

```
#left {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 300px;
  float:left;
}
#top {
  height: 45px;
  width: calc(100vw - 300px); // or calc(100% - 300px)
  margin: 0 0 0 300px;
}
#right {
  height: calc(100vh - 45px);
  width: 30%;
  float: right;
}
#middle {
  height: calc(100vh - 45px);
  margin: 0 30% 0 300px;
}
```

Comment: Could you use this in a jsfiddle example please? So I can see this better, thanks!

Comment: I'll try this on a jsfiddle by myself, thanks anyways :D

Answer (score 0):

The best is to use layering while thinking how you'll stack everything on top of each other. I've updated your jsFiddle here.

https://jsfiddle.net/L38cea2s/8/

```
html, body {
  height:100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#top {
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  top: 0;
  background-color:red;
  position: absolute;
}

#left {
  width:70%;
  height:100%;
  top: 0;
  background-color:green;
  position: absolute;
}

#right {
  width:30%;
  height:100%;
  top: 0;
  background-color:yellow;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Seeing the same as my jsfiddle, but now there's overflow on x and y

Comment: Sorry, I left the margins in. Since you're doing 100%, you don't want the body to have any portion.

Comment: Can't get what I want, because div left and right are under top div, and can't see the top of those divs

Comment: is this more what you're looking for?
https://jsfiddle.net/L38cea2s/11/

Keep in mind, because the height is 100% on the blue and purple divs, there will be overlap from the top div.

Comment: But green div still behind the red one

Comment: Isn't that what you want? it's 100%. If not, make it start at 50px height like the top is.
https://jsfiddle.net/L38cea2s/12/

Comment: Well no haha, now the green is behind yellow

Comment: in which case, you start the green 30% to the right .
https://jsfiddle.net/L38cea2s/14/